# How to remove overlap from time spans (SQL)

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of time spans that overlap each other. I want to generate a table that covers the same time spans but doesn't overlap.

For example, say I have a table like this:

```
Start,End
1,    4
3,    5
7,    8
2,    4
```

I want a new table like this:

```
Start,End
1,    5
7,    8
```

What is the SQL query to do this?

Comment: How do you know that you need to link only rows 1 and 2, not 1,2,3 or 1 and 4 or 2 and 4?

Comment: Prefer generic SQL but using Spark or Hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on spark-sql version  1.5.2.
(and with small changes - on Teradata, Oracle,  PostgreSQL and SQL Server)

In order to guarantee the correctness of this solution the `order by` clauses in the two analytic functions should be identical and deterministic, so if you have an Id column use **order by `Start`,`Id`** instead of **order by `Start`,`End`**

```
select  min(`Start`)    as `Start`
       ,max(`End`)      as `End`

from   (select  `Start`,`End`
               ,count(is_gap) over 
                (
                    order by   `Start`,`End` 
                    rows        unbounded preceding
                ) + 1 as range_seq

        from   (select  `Start`,`End`
                       ,case 
                            when max(`End`) over 
                                 (
                                    order by    `Start`,`End` 
                                    rows        between unbounded preceding 
                                                and     1 preceding
                                 ) < `Start` 
                            then 1 
                        end             is_gap

                from    mytable  
                ) t 
        ) t

group by  range_seq    

order by  `Start`
```

---

```
+-------+-----+
| Start | End |
+-------+-----+
| 1     | 5   |
+-------+-----+
| 7     | 8   |
+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Excellent answer. It can handle duplicate start, end records, too. Btw, the example table has a horrible column name (ie. End is a keyword). Most people probably don't need all the backticks. And they cause issues if you happen to have the query in a bash script but that's a different issue.